# How to extract column name and column type from SQL in pyspark

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The Spark SQL for Create query is like [this](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/create-table.html) -

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] [db_name.]table_name
  [(col_name1 col_type1 [COMMENT col_comment1], ...)]
  USING datasource
  [OPTIONS (key1=val1, key2=val2, ...)]
  [PARTITIONED BY (col_name1, col_name2, ...)]
  [CLUSTERED BY (col_name3, col_name4, ...) INTO num_buckets BUCKETS]
  [LOCATION path]
  [COMMENT table_comment]
  [TBLPROPERTIES (key1=val1, key2=val2, ...)]
  [AS select_statement]
```

where `[x]` means `x` is optional. I want the output as a tuple of following order if a `CREATE` sql query is passed -

```
(db_name, table_name, [(col1 name, col1 type), (col2 name, col2 type), ...])
```

So is there any way to do that with pyspark sql functions or need help from regex?

If regex could anyone please help with the regular expression?

Comment: Not a direct solution to your problem, but have considered the `describe table_name` statement after the query creation? Still, in the end you need to parse the result into the desired structure

Comment: I want the col name and type before running the CREATE query. There is a requirement for checking if the table is already present in DB or not with same col name and type.

Comment: Is order of columns important?

Comment: @thebluephantom yes very.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done by accessing the unofficial API through `java_gateway`:

```
plan = spark_session._jsparkSession.sessionState().sqlParser().parsePlan("CREATE TABLE foobar.test (foo INT, bar STRING) USING json")
print(f"database: {plan.tableDesc().identifier().database().get()}")
print(f"table: {plan.tableDesc().identifier().table()}")
# perhaps there is a better way to convert the schemas, using JSON string hack here
print(f"schema: {StructType.fromJson(json.loads(plan.tableDesc().schema().json()))}")
```

Output:

```
database: foobar
table: test
schema: StructType(List(StructField(foo,IntegerType,true),StructField(bar,StringType,true)))
```

Note that `database().get()` would fail if the database is not defined and the Scala option should be handled properly. Also, if you use `CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW` the accessors are named differently. The commands can be found here
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/ddl.scala#L38
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/ddl.scala#L58