# How to get the table name from Spark SQL Query [PySpark]?

Tags: python, sql, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

To get the table name from a SQL Query,

```sq
select *
from table1 as t1
full outer join table2 as t2
  on t1.id = t2.id
```

I found a solution in Scala [How to get table names from SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50899260/977038)

```scala
def getTables(query: String): Seq[String] = {
  val logicalPlan = spark.sessionState.sqlParser.parsePlan(query)
  import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedRelation
  logicalPlan.collect { case r: UnresolvedRelation => r.tableName }
}
```

which gives me the correct table names when I iterate over the return sequence `getTables(query).foreach(println)`

```
table1
table2
```

What would be the equivalent syntax for PySpark? The closest I came across was
[How to extract column name and column type from SQL in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56389617/977038)

```py
plan = spark_session._jsparkSession.sessionState().sqlParser().parsePlan(query)
print(f"table: {plan.tableDesc().identifier().table()}")
```

which fails with the traceback

```
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o78.tableDesc. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method tableDesc([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

> I understand, the problem stems up from the fact that I need to filter all plan items which are of type `UnresolvedRelation` but I cannot find an equivalent notation in python/pyspark

Comment: Could you please explain the scenario? You get a joined dataframe from someone and simply want to know which tables he has used to create that dataframe?

Comment: If you're really only after table names from text queries (that is, not built via dataframe API) maybe a simple SQL parser will do? https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse

Answer (score 4):

I have an approach, but rather convoluted. It dumps the Java Object and JSON (a poor man's serialization process), deserializes it to python object, filter and parse the table names

```py
import json
def get_tables(query: str):
    plan = spark._jsparkSession.sessionState().sqlParser().parsePlan(query)
    plan_items = json.loads(plan.toJSON())
    for plan_item in plan_items:
        if plan_item['class'] == 'org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedRelation':
            yield plan_item['tableIdentifier']['table']
```

which yields `['fast_track_gv_nexus', 'buybox_gv_nexus']` when I iterate over the function `list(get_tables(query))`

**Note** Unfortunately, this breaks for [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms190766(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Example

```sql
with delta as (
   select *
    group by id
    cluster by id
 )
select   *
  from ( select  *
         FROM
          (select   *
            from dmm
            inner join delta on dmm.id = delta.id
           )
  )
```

And to resolve it, I have to hack around through regular expression

```py
import json
import re
def get_tables(query: str):
    plan = spark._jsparkSession.sessionState().sqlParser().parsePlan(query)
    plan_items = json.loads(plan.toJSON())
    plan_string = plan.toString()
    cte = re.findall(r"CTE \[(.*?)\]", plan_string)
    for plan_item in plan_items:
        if plan_item['class'] == 'org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedRelation':
            tableIdentifier = plan_item['tableIdentifier']
            table =  plan_item['tableIdentifier']['table']   
            database =  tableIdentifier.get('database', '')
            table_name = "{}.{}".format(database, table) if database else table
            if table_name not in cte:
                yield table_name
```